# CSS rotating 3 blocks

Tags: html, css

For my project I'm trying make 3 blocks with a rotation of 9 degrees. Unfortunately I get some white space and I can't get rid of it.

**Example**

```css
.homeholder {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.homeholder .box {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 5px);
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(9deg);
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.homeholder .box.restaurant {
  background-color: red;
}

.homeholder .box.rooms {
  background-color: blue;
}

.homeholder .box.about {
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="homeholder">
  <div class="box restaurant"></div>
  <div class="box rooms"></div>
  <div class="box about"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Avoid using `float` in 2023

Comment: Why don't you just use a gradient background at an angle? And why the margin?

Comment: Why have a right margin on each box?

Comment: Also why the magic number `5` in `width: calc((100% / 3) - 5px);`

Comment: Was this the desired? https://jsfiddle.net/otvr3z05/  PS:  how is this supposed to behave on responsive?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The thing I'm trying to achieve is to have 3 clickable blocks on the page like this: https://imgur.com/a/DtRGPXs

The colors are just for the first step.

I used a margin on the blocks because they where overlapping a little, so I used the -5px in the calc because they won't fit next to eachother.

Comment: read this: https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-and-custom-shapes-part-2/ and thank me later. A quite long article but it worth it